# TeeChart (JavaAndroid 2012) tutorial sample causes UnsupportedOperationException

Tags: android, exception, charts, teechart

I am trying to work through an example of TeeChart from their tutorial ( first one ).
For some reason when I run the code below it causes an UnsupportedOperationException to occur.
Can anyone offer any help on why this might occur.

Below are the relevant files.

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.example.teeChart02"
          android:versionCode="1"
          android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15"/>
    <application android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher">
        <activity android:name="MyActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

**main.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:id="@+id/mylayout">
</LinearLayout>
```

**MyActivity.java**

```
package com.example.teeChart02;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import com.steema.teechart.TChart;
import com.steema.teechart.drawing.Color;
import com.steema.teechart.styles.Bar;
import com.steema.teechart.styles.Series;

public class MyActivity extends Activity
{
    private TChart chart;

    @Override
    public void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState )
    {
        super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
        setContentView( R.layout.main );

        LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById( R.id.mylayout );

        chart = new TChart( this );
        ll.addView( chart );

        Series bar = new Bar( chart.getChart() );
        chart.getAxes().getBottom().setIncrement( 1 );
        bar.add( 123, "Apples", Color.green );
        bar.add( 456, "Oranges", Color.red );
        bar.add( 321, "Kiwis", Color.yellow );
        bar.add( 78, "Bananas", Color.orange );
    }
}
```

Exception that is generated is:

```
01-17 11:50:27.863: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1631): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
        at android.view.GLES20Canvas.clipPath(GLES20Canvas.java:413)
        at com.steema.teechart.android.Graphics3DAndroid.clipPolygon(Graphics3DAndroid.java:312)
        at com.steema.teechart.drawing.Graphics3D.clipToRight(Graphics3D.java:4575)
        at com.steema.teechart.drawing.Graphics3D.clipCube(Graphics3D.java:4614)
        at com.steema.teechart.styles.Series.clipRegionCreate(Series.java:2088)
        at com.steema.teechart.styles.Series.drawSeries(Series.java:2311)
        at com.steema.teechart.Chart.drawAllSeries(Chart.java:790)
        at com.steema.teechart.Chart.drawAxesSeries(Chart.java:752)
        at com.steema.teechart.Chart.internalDraw(Chart.java:732)
        at com.steema.teechart.Chart.paint(Chart.java:2080)
        at com.steema.teechart.Chart.paint(Chart.java:2096)
        at com.steema.teechart.TChart.onDraw(TChart.java:322)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:10978)
        at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10417)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2850)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2489)
        at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10415)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2850)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2489)
        at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10415)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2850)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2489)
        at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10415)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2850)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2489)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:10981)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:450)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:2126)
        at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10417)
        at android.view.HardwareRenderer$GlRenderer.draw(HardwareRenderer.java:842)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:1910)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1634)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2442)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 2):

Please check if you have selected the TeeChart.Android.jar library in the "Project properties -> Java Build Path -> Order and Export" tab

Comment: I select TeeChart.Android.jar but it doesn't help. In app manifest android:minSdkVersion=15 and when I changed it to 8 it worked. UnsupportedOperationException is occured when android:minSdkVersion>=14.

Answer (score 1):

I was working along just fine with TeeChart with a minSdkVersion of 11 and a target of 13.  As soon as I switch over to a minSdkVersion of 12 and a target of 15, I started receiving the exact same error.  I haven't yet take the time to figure out which was the problem, but as soon as I switch back to 11 and 13 the problem went away